# Oracle case inside where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, where-clause

This is a simple question, I've read some details about using `CASE` in `WHERE` clause, but couldn't able to make a clear idea how to use it. The below is my sample query:

```
1    SELECT * FROM dual
2    WHERE (1 =1)
3     AND (SYSDATE+1 > SYSDATE)
4     AND (30 > 40)
5     AND (25 < 35);
```

I have a procedure `i_value` as in parameter.
I need to ignore the 4th line if i_value is 'S' and I need to ignore the 5th line if i_value is 'T'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the best way to solve your problem:

```
select *
from dual
where (1 = 1)
      and (sysdate + 1 > sysdate)
      and case
            when i_value = 'S'
              then
                case
                  when (25 < 35)
                    then 1
                    else 0
                end
            when i_value = 'T'
              then
                case
                  when (30 > 40)
                    then 1
                    else 0
                end
          end = 1;
```

Of course, you could use Dynamic SQL, but it'd be more difficult and less effective.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * FROM dual
 WHERE (1 =1)
 AND (SYSDATE+1 > SYSDATE)
 AND CASE WHEN i_value = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN (30 > 40) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1
 AND CASE WHEN i_value = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN (25 < 35) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1;
```

Comment: This will not work as expected. Because if the i_value is passed as 'S', then the 4th line in your code results to 0 and the condition fails. so, the whole output would be none. Have a deep look .

Comment: Oops - I have updated it to fix the problem. (Previously had "AND CASE WHEN i_value = 'S' THEN 0 ELSE ... " have changed the 0 to 1 on both the 4th & 5th lines.

Answer (score 2):

Why <s>so ser</s> use `case`?

```
 SELECT * FROM dual
  WHERE (1 =1)
    AND ( SYSDATE+1 > SYSDATE )
    AND ( ((30 > 40) and i_value <> 'S') or i_value = 'S' )
    AND ( ((25 < 35) and i_value <> 'T') or i_value = 'T' );
```

Comment: This is better anyway. But not appropriate to my code. (the above is a sample query I used from a big query).  So I have used "if i_value ='S' then" method. Otherwise , I should have to use a big hardcoding on each line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well.

```
case
  when (i_value = 'S' and (WHERE (1=1) AND (SYSDATE+1 > SYSDATE) AND (25 < 35)) ) then 1
  when (i_value = 'T' and (WHERE (1=1) AND (SYSDATE+1 > SYSDATE) AND (30 < 40)) ) then 1
  else 0
end = 1
```